# php - How to checking when the user come back, after log out?

Tags: php, session, authentication, isset, login-control

I wanted to make a log in and log out page, in php.
I made so far all the code, but exept that I don't know how to check if the variable `$_SESSION['login']` is set or not. I tried use `isset();` `unset();` `session_destroy();` ... and still didn't resolve it.
I wanted this, because I want to redirect to a page, if an user press the back button from the browser. ;) I like to be like google, and other big pro websites. ;)

I toke the code from : https://www.formget.com/login-form-in-php/, and I adapted it.

session.php

```
    <?php
    session_start(); 
    $user_check = '';

        // I will not give you my passwords so easly :P
    define('DB_USER', ' ');
    define('DB_PSWD', ' ');
    define('DB_HOST', ' ');
    define('DB_NAME', ' ');

    $connection = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST,DB_USER,DB_PSWD,DB_NAME) or die(mysql_error());

    $user_check = $_SESSION['loginUser'];


    $ses_sql = mysqli_query($connection,"SELECT Name FROM Passwords WHERE Name='$user_check'");
    $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($ses_sql);
    $login = $row['Name'];


    if(!isset($login)){
        mysql_close($connection);
        header("location : ../Resource.php"); // redirect
    }

?>
```

Please help !

UPDATE 1 :
Also I have the logout.php like this :

```
<?php
    session_start();
    session_destroy();
    header("location: ../Resource.php"); // redirect
?>
```

And at login page, I passed the username throught `$_SESSION['loginUser']`

Comment: if they ahve looged out, you wont have " $_SESSION['loginUser']" will you?

Comment: This solution is vulnerable to SQL INJECTION. Anyway you could check it with empty();

Comment: yes @rtfm . you are right ! That's I put it the UPDATE 1, for you

Comment: @miclen , it's still vulnerable if I ecrypt the password in the login page ?

Comment: I checked with empty, and yet nothing to work ... :(

Comment: If I were to attempt login with my valid username and password, but I input my username as `myname' AND LEFT(CURRENT_USER,1)='A` then your site will happily tell me whether your `DB_USER` starts with an `A`. If not, login will fail. Repeat as needed until I have your username. I can also use this to extract information from your database, eg. get stuff from `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` and eventually run `myname' AND LEFT((select Name from Passwords where Role='Admin'),1)='A` allows me to (hopefully) extract the username of an administrator.

Comment: @CristianFlorescu you have to remove special chars in variable

Comment: nope. isn't that either. :(

Comment: Do I prevent mysql injection issue, if I will check if  `$_SESSION['LoginUser'];` and `$_SESSION['PasswordUser'];` both are true ?

Comment: You might find https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_Injection_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet helpful. /cc @miclen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`isset()` will work for sessions. If you write:

```
if(isset($_SESSION['loginUser'])) {
    // Your code
}
```

That will work. You can also use `empty()` instead of `isset()` to check if the session is empty, but generally checking if a session is set is good enough for the validation you're performing.

I've run into server that won't set the session before the page is processed and you need to redirect the user to the next page, and then the session will appear valid. This is common with cookies, too.

You're also checking to see if there is anything returned and redirecting if `$login` is not set -- but you're *always* setting it, so your redirect will never run.

Here's a better solution (using your current code; excluding SQL injection  concerns that others have mentioned, that's a different topic).

```
// Limit your query to one result to MySQL will stop searching once it's found a match. 
$ses_sql = mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT Name FROM Passwords WHERE Name='$user_check' LIMIT 1");

if($ses_sql->num_rows == 1) {
    // A row was found, do something.
} else {
    // No rows were found, do something else.
}
```

Now you have less variables, you're using the assigned data given with MySQLi, it's lines, less searching the DB has to do when a result is found, and you have a match/no-match scenario.

Comment: Thanks Kalob ! :) It still not working, but I guess it's a problem from the server.

Comment: I take you example and make a apropiate verification, like you

Comment: One question remaining : what `$ses_sql->num_rows` means ?
it takes the number of rows, and it put in the variable num_rows, right ? :D

Comment: `$ses_sql->num_rows` returns the number of rows found in your MySQLi query. You did a LIMIT 1, do the `num_rows` will only ever be 1 or 0.